# Best way to recover from a failed model save in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, rails-activerecord

I have some code to get some tweets from the twitter API:

```
initial_tweets = get_tweets_in_time_range self.name, (Time.now-1.weeks), Time.now 

initial_tweets.each do |tweet|
    new_tweet = Tweet.new

    new_tweet.favorite_count = tweet.favorite_count 
    new_tweet.filter_level = tweet.filter_level 
    new_tweet.retweet_count = tweet.retweet_count 
    new_tweet.text = tweet.text 
    new_tweet.tweeted_at = tweet.created_at 

    new_tweet.created_at = DateTime.strptime tweet.created_at.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z' 

    new_tweet.save 
    # What happens on a failed save
end
```

Whats the correct fallback if that save fails? As pointed out where the comment is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"the correct fallback"* doesn't exists, it all depends on your code. You could just ignore the failed save and continue with the next tweet, you could break the loop at that point, or you could wrap everything in a transaction and invoke a rollback. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` only return true or false, you can use `save!`,  it will raise an exception if the record is invalid. if exception raised, you can catch it.

```
begin
  ....
  new_tweet.save!
rescue exception => e
  puts e.inspect
  #you can continue the loop or exit
end
```

as @Stefan said, you can wrap you code in a transaction, if one record save failed, all saved record will rollback. I don't advise you to do this unless you really want every record saved success.

```
Tweet.transaction do
   initial_tweets = get_tweets_in_time_range self.name, (Time.now-1.weeks), Time.now 
initial_tweets.each do |tweet|
    new_tweet = Tweet.new
    ..... 
    new_tweet.created_at = DateTime.strptime tweet.created_at.to_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z' 

    new_tweet.save! # you have to add '!', once save failed, it will trigger rolls back.
  end
end
```

Comment: Or just `unless new_tweet.save ...`

Comment: What I'm curious about is either way, what is the best course of action to take? If the save fails.. whats the best course of action? Do I print to console or just return an error to the front? How would I return an error to the front?

Comment: @NNNNNNNNNNDelicious If save failed, you can print the error message, then continue the loop or exit the loop depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you, also thanks for the multiple solutions its nice to see different ways of solving the problem.